# Optimizing a select from a large table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with around 40 million rows, and I want to run something like this:

```
SELECT country, count(*) FROM `signups`
where `signed_up` > '2012-03-20 00:00:00'
group by country
```

Basically to get how many sign ups per country after certain dates (usually for the last week). There are around 400K sign-ups per day, and 40 million in total or so.

The query just doesn't run for the last week, I get a 'MySQL server has gone away'... Any ways of optimizing this?

Comment: What indexes do you have on `countries`?

Comment: Only one index, primary key which is signup_id

Comment: Always use the **EXPLAIN** SELECT ... command to see how your DB is going to answer your query. An index on signed_up would also not hurt since your searching on this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query and add a index on signed_up column. You will surely get performance gain.

SELECT country, count(signup_id) FROM `signups`
where `signed_up` > '2012-03-20 00:00:00'
group by country

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1):

Counting * is a hit to the perfomance.  It's always better, if possible, to not do * anything.  It's just caused the DB engine to do more work, thus slowing the query down.

Alok is right, add an index to the columns you generally search on and the hash table will already be created when the query runs.  Otherwise the engine will need to create the hash table of the results before it can actually get the results.  The index does this before hand.